# Jetty 7 Continuations: How to *not* redispatch the request?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jetty

I'm using Jetty 7 continuations to implement some asynchronous processing.  What I'm trying to do is start off the continuation (via .suspend()), and then hand the continuation off to some other object that will compose the response, which works fine.  But Jetty keeps redispatching the response (with isInitial = false) to the servlet, and I don't want or need that, because the response is being dealt with by some other object.

So, I'd like to find a way to explicitly *not* redispatch the request on timeout or expire, because I'm using an event-driven series of callbacks to actually produce the response.

Comment: I've come across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123888/how-to-use-jetty-continuations-with-a-filter-and-forward-dispatching, which may answer this question

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation around `continuation.isInitial()` - from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations:

> #### Resuming a Request
>
> Once an asynchronous event has
>   occurred, the continuation can be
>   resumed:
>
> ```
> void myAsyncCallback(Object results)
> {
>     continuation.setAttribute("results",results);
>     continuation.resume();
> }
> ```
>
> When a continuation is resumed, the
>   request is redispatched to the servlet
>   container, almost as if the request
>   had been received again. However
>   during the redispatch, the
>   `continuation.isInitial()` method
>   returns false and any attributes set
>   by the asynchronous handler are
>   available.